# How can I validate if an input is enabled in Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to validate if an input is enabled at the time that I want to execute the test project.

[image: Input]

The input is enabled if a product needs a serial number, but if it doesn't need it, it's not enabled. It's XPath is: `//*[@id="cantidad"]`

If the input is enabled I need to type a serial number, but if it´s not enabled I need to continue with the test project.

Comment: I don't the syntax for c# but logic wise it be ```if Browser.find_elements_by_id("cantidad"):
``` enter serial number

Comment: the problem is that the element is always in the html. But sometimes is enabled to type in

Comment: use ExpectedCondition of "elementToBeClickable": https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable(org.openqa.selenium.WebElement)  "Returns: WebElement once it is clickable (visible and enabled)"

Comment: in python we have ```WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.id, ""cantidad"")))``` this waits 10 seconds to see if its clickable

Comment: What have you tried so far?